# How to fill a scattered region in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've data file containing random scattered data over x,y plane. All I want is to fill the scattered  region with solid color. My data are not sorted. I've tried to use scatterplot in matplotlib but the number of points in my data file are quite large, so plotting them in scatter make the resulting plot quite big in size. The scattered data form small islands over the x,y plane.

Comment: Can you use a contour plot? See [`matplotlib.pyplot.contourf`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.contourf) for example.

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate a histogram (2D) of the x, y values using numpy's [histogram2d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html) method. Then you plot the array that is true for all non-zero bins and false for all zero bins. You can control the resolution of the histogram using the `bins` parameter. This method returns a tuple of 3 arrays: the 2D histogram and two 1D arrays corresponding the bin steps along each 'edge' (x then y). You can control the step values using the `range` parameter.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(101)
x = np.random.normal(0,1,10000)
y = np.random.normal(0,1,10000)

hist,xedge,yedge= np.histogram2d(x,y,bins=100,range=[[-4,4],[-4,4]])

plt.imshow(hist==0,
           origin='lower',
           cmap=plt.gray(),
           extent=[xedge[0],xedge[-1],yedge[0],yedge[-1]])

plt.savefig('hist2d.png')
plt.show()
```

This results in:

[image]

The black points show where you have any data, the white points are where there is no data. The histogram is presented using the `imshow` method, which is used to plot images or matrices. By default it set's the origin to the top left, so you will either want to change the parameter `origin='lower'`, or you want to appropriately adjust the `extent` parameter, which controls the range values: [intial x, final x, initial y, final y]. You can control the color scheme by adjusting the [color map](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.colormaps).

As @joaquin mentions in the comments, you can also simply plot `imshow(hist)` to see the full range of values (heatmap), rather than 0 or 1.

Comment: +1 You could have a heatmap just doing `plt.imshow(hist)`. Maybe the OP likes it better as it gives sense of density at each point not just yes/no (and it is nicer)

Comment: +1 As a side note, though, `histogram2d` is inefficient for large numbers of points.  You'll run into memory problems if you use it for more than a few tens of thousands of points.  It becomes much faster to either iterate or trick `scipy.sparse.coo_matrix` into doing it for you.

Comment: Woops, partially scratch my previous comment, it's quite fast if you have a small number of bins, even with a large number of points.  It becomes less efficient than other solutions when you have both a large number of bins and a large number of points.  Also, my memory of it being inefficient was based on a much earlier version. It's still reasonably efficient even in those cases with recent versions of numpy.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something this does not answer the original question at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
x=np.random.rand(10)
y=np.random.rand(10)
plt.figure()
plt.fill(x,y,'b')
plt.show()
```

[image: what I got]

There is also a fill_between to fill between two lines
[matplotlib documentation of them both](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill)